# Turtlebot wheel tf jumping

Tags: turtlebot, robot-state-publisher, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I see TF from base_footprint to wheel links are slightly jumping when it is moving while sending Twist message( (-)0.5 x vel)) using teleop_twist_keyboard.

Has anyone seen this problem?

http://files.yujinrobot.com/turtlebot/wheel_jumping_turtlebot.ogv

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/58512/turtlebot-wheel-tf-jumping/) by [jihoonl](https://answers.ros.org/users/830/jihoonl/) on ROS Answers with karma: 634 on 2013-03-18

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bit-pirate](https://answers.ros.org/users/62/bit-pirate/) on 2013-03-18**:
We are using Precise + Groovy here.

**Comment by [jihoonl](https://answers.ros.org/users/830/jihoonl/) on 2013-03-18**:
We also have tested with different robot_state_publisher publish_frequency. But it was not a slow update issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This looks like different timing.  rviz by default renders the latest information about every link.  There's an experimental button you could try at the bottom right (in the time bar) to see if it "fixes" it?

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-06-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0